# filtering rows in pandas dataframe with a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is tab-separated. I would like to get the rows containing a specific string in the first part of the third column.
See this example:

```
col1       col2    col3    

a            a1    good | bad 

b            b1    bad | bad 

c            c1    foogood | foobad 

d            d1    bad | good  

e            e1    good | good  

f            f1    bad | foobad
```

Here, I want to separate the third column on the `|` character. I then want to take the ones having string `good` in the first part. So the desired output would be

```
 col1           col2        col3    

    a            a1       good | bad 

    c            c1       foogood | foobad 

    e            e1        good | good
```

I know that this can be done using the `apply` function, but I don't know how to define such a function using `apply`. I also tried filtering using `[]` but could not get it to work. Appreciate your help brothers and sisters.

**Update**: I also have the underlying TSV file and know this can be done using `grep` and `awk` as well. So either solution is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `str.split` with `contains`

```
yourdf=df[df.col3.str.split('|').str[0].str.contains('good')]
```

Comment: Since you don't need any regex patterns in your string, you can set `regex=False` +1

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with awk.

```
$ cat file
col1    col2    col3
a       a1      good | bad
b       b1      bad | bad
c       c1      foogood | foobad
d       d1      bad | good
e       e1      good | good
f       f1      bad | foobad
$
$ awk -F $'\t' '(NR == 1 || $3 ~ /^[^|]*good/)' file
col1    col2    col3
a       a1      good | bad
c       c1      foogood | foobad
e       e1      good | good
```

Also, you can give `sed` a try:

```
sed -n '1p; /^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^|]*good/p' file
```

which produces the desired result as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the required text starts with `good`, and is always followed by `|`, then you can combine these into a single substring (with this order) directly in `.contains()`. Pandas can filter out these rows.

Input DF

```
df
  col1 col2              col3
0    a   a1        good | bad
1    b   b1         bad | bad
2    c   c1  foogood | foobad
3    d   d1        bad | good
4    e   e1       good | good
5    f   f1      bad | foobad
```

Filtered DF

```
df[df['col3'].str.contains('good | \n')]
  col1 col2              col3
0    a   a1        good | bad
2    c   c1  foogood | foobad
4    e   e1       good | good
```

You could do the same with `bad` (instead of `good`)

```
df[df['col3'].str.contains('bad | \n')]
  col1 col2          col3
1    b   b1     bad | bad
3    d   d1    bad | good
5    f   f1  bad | foobad
```